# VBA Boolean values not evaluating correctly and therefore giving the wrong output

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

[image: Worksheet "Tabelle1"]

```
Dim EmailSent As String
Dim WindowEnd As Date
Dim TimeWindowEnd As Date
Dim MailToBeSent As Range, TotalMailsToBeSent As Range
Dim RouteLoaded As Range, TotalLoadedRoutes As Range
Dim RouteOrdered As Range, TotalOrderedRoutes As Range
Dim RouteName As Range, AllRouteNames As Range
Dim TwEnd As Range, AllTwEnd As Range
Dim RequiredRoute As Boolean
Dim LoadedRoute As Boolean
Dim WindowOver As Boolean
Dim CurrentTime As Date
Dim WindowTime As Date

Sub check()

    Set AllRouteNames = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A3:A" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        For Each RouteName In AllRouteNames.Cells
        Next RouteName

    Set AllTwEnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("D3:D" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        For Each TwEnd In AllTwEnd.Cells
            CurrentTime = Now()
            WindowTime = Format(TwEnd.Value, "HH:MM")
            If WindowTime < Format(CurrentTime, "HH:MM") Then
                WindowOver = True
                MsgBox (WindowTime)
            ElseIf WindowTime > Format(CurrentTime, "HH:MM") Then
                WindowOver = False
                MsgBox (WindowTime)
            End If
        Next TwEnd

    Set TotalOrderedRoutes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("E3:E" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        For Each RouteOrdered In TotalOrderedRoutes.Cells
            If RouteOrdered = "N" Or RouteOrdered = " " Then
                RequiredRoute = False
            ElseIf RouteOrdered = "J" Then
                RequiredRoute = True
            End If
        Next RouteOrdered

    Set TotalLoadedRoutes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("F3:F" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        For Each RouteLoaded In TotalLoadedRoutes.Cells
            If RouteLoaded = "N" Then
               LoadedRoute = False
            ElseIf RouteLoaded = "J" Then
                LoadedRoute = True
            End If
       Next RouteLoaded

    Set TotalMailsToBeSent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("G3:G" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        For Each MailToBeSent In TotalMailsToBeSent.Cells
            If MailToBeSent = "J" Or LoadedRoute = True Then                                                           'Mail was sent (either entered manually at beginning or via script)
                MsgBox ("Mail was already sent or route already loaded")
                MsgBox ("Required route is " & RequiredRoute)
                MailToBeSent.Value = "J"
            ElseIf MailToBeSent = " " And RequiredRoute = True And WindowOver = True Then        'Mail wasn't sent, route will load today and time window is over
                MsgBox ("MailSent is empty and time window is over, sending e-mail now..")
                Call CreateMailAndSend
                MailToBeSent.Value = "J"
            ElseIf MailToBeSent = " " And RequiredRoute = True And WindowOver = False Then    'Mail wasn't sent, route will load today and time window isn't over
                MsgBox ("MailSent is empty but time window is not over yet")
                MsgBox ("Required route is " & RequiredRoute)
            End If
        Next MailToBeSent

End Sub
```

My problem is that this script successfully loops through each the columns I want, but for example under "bestellt", where a J is clearly showing, the boolean will evaluate as false and therefore will not do what I need it to do.

Can anyone see how I could improve this or what I'm doing wrong? This is the first script I've written in VBA and want to learn.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you only want *one* loop here - loop through column A and then refer to the cells in the other columns using `Offset`.

Comment: @BigBen I had this thought too, but I couldn't get the loop to work. I found this way to be easier. Could you give me an example of how I would fit two of these into one loop?

Comment: `For Each RouteName in AllRouteNames`... `Set TwEnd = RoutName.Offset(,3)` for example.

Comment: Or you could make this an actual table (`ListObject`) using Ctrl+T or whatever the shortcut is in your Excel version (don't know if it's different across versions). Then you just would iterate through the `ListRows`.

Comment: Your first three lines in sub check do nothing. The bit that starts Set TotalOrderedRoutes  changes a memory variable to false or true lots of times, but at the end it will hold whatever was set by the last row. So when it goes into  Set TotalMailsToBeSent it will be either true or false, but it won't magically look back at what you did on that row in TotalOrderedRoutes

Comment: @HarassedDad What I was trying to do was to store each variable for every row instead of constantly overwriting it until the last variable was reached. This explains what is happening and why I'm getting the results I'm getting. Is there a way to have a variable saved from every line?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @BigBen I'm trying to loop through each column and evaluate each row (usually if 2 parameters are true) which will give an outcome. The script would run by itself every so often, so I need it to be able to save the booleans for each row in a variable.

Comment: But what is the script doing with each row? Sending an email for each row? "Saving booleans for each row" - this smells very fishy. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BigBen It basically needs to evaluate if an e-mail needs to be sent, once I had the logic I would move on to extracting the appropriate contact and information to send the e-mail automatically. The boolean just helps to evaluate if an e-mail needs to be sent or not.

Comment: IMO you should loop row by row, figure out if the email should be sent, then send it... instead of trying to "store" all the relevant information.

Comment: @BigBen I think you're right, thank you for your help.